# React Material UI Change Height of Textfield

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How do I properly change the height of React Material UI v4 Textfield?
The following code messes up the label. Looking for a simple and easy method.

```
export const useTextFieldStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    minHeight: '42px',
  },
});

<TextField
{...params}
margin="dense"
value={listItem}
InputProps={{
  classes: {
    input: textFieldStyles.root,
  },
}}
/>
```

[image]

Referring to this link: [Set TextField height material-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53854030/set-textfield-height-material-ui)

Comment: Have you tried height instead of minHeight? Is it the same behaviour with the label?

Comment: Hi @AymenHammami I have tried both ways

Comment: did you checked `size` props of `TextField` also you can use the `sx` props and directly add height.

Comment: hi, I have MU version 4, so I don't believe sx is possible,  size does not work either

Comment: hi @AymenHammami why was this voted down? thanks, trying to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with changing style of mui component in your style classes like this

```
MuiInputLabel-outlined.MuiInputLabel-shrink 
{
  padding: .3rem !important;
  transform: translate(-14px, -14px) scale(0.7) !important;
}
```

You can change my params

Comment: please upvote my question also, thanks, I sent points

Answer (score 1):

The `input` element has a padding and is wrapped inside a `div`.
To change the padding use:

```
<TextField
  inputProps={{ style: { padding: '10px' } }}
  ...
/>
```

You can use this for basically any style.

Comment: Nice way of doing it, I've added it to the field I needed it on instead of globally