# Reducing height of textfield in MaterialUI below "small"

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-ui

I am using TextField component of MUI for a task and I am already using a `size="small"` which still has a greater height than what I need. How can I reduce it further? Custom styling, using `style={{height: "5px"}}` doesn't seem to work in reducing the height of the box of the textfield itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set TextField height material-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53854030/set-textfield-height-material-ui)

Comment: @Kundan Nope, it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this option:

```
sx={{ "& .MuiInputBase-input": { fontSize: 10, height: 4, padding: 1 } }}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Can you explain briefly what it does and why can't this be done using `styles`?

Comment: In this case, this can be done through 'style', but 'sx' has advanced capabilities:
https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/ Your problem is that the 'TextField' component
consists of several nested elements and you must explicitly indicate which of them the styles are applied to.